# Javascript : Replace Detect a string and replace html in a div after changing color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to change color of a part of strings. I have a list of DOM elements, and for each of them, the text can contain some hashtags. I would like to put in color all hashtags words which could be found in the text.

Here is the begin of the code :

```
var listOfText = document.getElementsByClassName("titleTweet");
                        for (var nodetext in listOfText) {
                            var divContent = listOfText[nodetext].innerHTML;
                            if (divContent.indexOf("#") !== -1) {
                                // Do job here
                            }
                        }
```

For example, divContent can be equals to "**Hello my #friends ! How are you ?**"

I would like to update the dom elements to put in red color the word "**#friends**".

I don't know how to do that using javascript or jQuery.

Comment: wrap specific substring inside any inline block tag as span, this is the general idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regexp to find the hastags and wrap them with html.  Then use the .html() method to replace the original element's html with the new string.

Example snippet

```
$('#myDiv').replace(/#[a-z0-1A-Z]+/g, '<span style="color: red;">$&</span>'));
```

Working example - http://jsfiddle.net/4p4mA/1/

Edited the example to work on all divs on the page.

Note: This will only work so long as your element only contains text, because it is replacing all the child nodes with its text value.

Comment: It works but only for the first element found by JQuery. How can i do that for all id ?

Comment: What are you storing the text in? A different selector will get you different elements to replace on.  $('div') for example matches all divs on the page, or $('div.hashtag') matches all divs with the class hashtag.

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique values.  jQuery respects this, so when you try to match against and id ('#text') it will only return the first one that it finds.  If you changed the id to be a class and updated the selector, that would work.

You should try to make your selectors as specific as possible though so you don't match stuff by mistake.

 Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4p4mA/6/

Answer (score 1):

use regex for this, find text having hashtag and replave that in span tag for each element.

```
$('.titleTweet').each(function(){
    var $this=$(this);
$this.html($this.text()
                .replace(/#[a-z0-1A-Z]+/g, '<span style="color: red;">$&</span>'));
});
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4p4mA/4/)

Answer (score 0):

`.innerHTML` is a poor basis to starting replacing text. You'll want to navigate down to the text nodes and use `.nodeValue` to get the text. Then you can start splitting up the text nodes.